# Causes of "cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" other than multiple contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a base object, which creates a new repository when created:

```
    protected static RecRepository rep
    {
        get
        {
            if (_rep == null)
                _rep = new RecRepository();
            return _rep;
        }
    }
```

Object which inherit from this then have a unified `rep` object that I can use, working from a single database context.

This has worked fine so far. However, I've just added a new block of code that adds a new object. The repository code looks like this:

```
    public void Counts_Add(Count count)
    {
        if (db.Counts.Any(m => m.CountID == count.CountID))
        {
            db.Entry(count).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            db.Counts.Add(Count);
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel that calls this inherits from my base object and so has a rep available and it uses that rep - and thus the same context - for all database operations. It's been working fine so far.

However, when add my new `Count` object and `SaveChanges()` I end up getting the error

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker
```

I've only seen this before when I've been attempting to use multiple database contexts. But I can't see in this instance that that's a possible source of the problem.

So - am I right in thinking that my base object static property will ensure all operations on child objects use the same context? And if so, what other possible causes of this error are there? Google just keeps coming up with situations where the same object is being manipulated by different contexts, since that's the most common cause.

Comment: Matt - Hi, hope you are well.  You've misunderstood that only one Repository will exist here.  You can approach this two ways, create a singleton Repository outside of the base class and reference that from the those who inherit or implement an IUnitOfWork that is registered with each repository.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898538/iunitofwork-how-to-use-best-practice

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks - I did stumble over the right answer in the end, was just confused, as you said, over the number of contexts that were being created in this situation. Hope things are good with you, too :)

Answer (score 0):

just to check, can you try this code:

```
private static Object thisLock = new Object();

protected static RecRepository rep
{
    get
    {
        lock ( thisLock ) {
            if (_rep == null)
                _rep = new RecRepository();
        }
        return _rep;
    }
}
```

===== ===== ===== ===== ===== =====

imho the code firing is the following:

```
    // <summary>
    // When attaching we need to check that the entity is not already attached to a different context
    // before we wipe away that context.
    // </summary>
    private void VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
    {
        if (wrappedEntity.Context != null
            && wrappedEntity.Context != this
            && !wrappedEntity.Context.ObjectStateManager.IsDisposed
            && wrappedEntity.MergeOption != MergeOption.NoTracking)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings.Entity_EntityCantHaveMultipleChangeTrackers);
        }
    }
```

my best guess is: `count` parameter correspond to an existing entity. A Count object is in the context with the same CountID. `db.Entry(count)` add a new Count entity that should confuse the tracker.

so try :

```
public void Counts_Add(Count count)
{
    if (db.Counts.Any(m => m.CountID == count.CountID))
    {
        Count c = db.Counts.Local.Where(m => m.CountID == count.CountID).FirstOrDefault();
        if ( c!= null ) {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Detach(c);
        }
        db.Entry(count).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
    {
        db.Counts.Add(Count);
    }
}
```

===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== =====

the only other point from where this exception is fired is from this code:

```
    // <summary>
    // When attaching we need to check that the entity is not already attached to a different context
    // before we wipe away that context.
    // </summary>
    private void VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
    {
        if (wrappedEntity.Context != null
            && wrappedEntity.Context != this
            && !wrappedEntity.Context.ObjectStateManager.IsDisposed
            && wrappedEntity.MergeOption != MergeOption.NoTracking)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings.Entity_EntityCantHaveMultipleChangeTrackers);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying to help. Still getting the same error. Is there a way to get EF to tell you which context(s) it thinks an object is attached to?

Comment: no, but I suggest a new try. Of course all this strongly depends of Count properties (is there some complex property ?).

Comment: That's not it - this error is firing on the Add. So it can't be because the object already exists. Unless it's somehow connected to a changes to a child/parent object. But I appreciate you trying to help out.